# dynamic flter with views

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to display dynamic result based on the URL, with the [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)?

I have a database table with thousand messages, and I would display those containing the words in the URL. For example, with `test.com/variableparent/variableschild`, it should display the text containing the  *variables_child* variable.

I tried with the filter, but I have to put a specific word, not a dynamic one.

Comment: try to use php code. Global:PHP

Comment: Really, _really_, don't use the PHP filter.

Comment: [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)

Comment: did you tried entity reference view?

Comment: @ReesGargi I take the OP is not talking of entity references, but rather a plain database table containing messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Views Argument Substitutions](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_substitutions) and I'm just assuming the Title field here. It should work for any text field.

1. Add some `Global: Null` contextual filters to take each raw component of the url. (Provide default: Raw Value from URL 2 / 3 / 4 etc.
2. In your views filters, add Title: Contains: `***!1***`. Repeat this for however many url components there are. `***!2***` `***!3***` etc. for each Title filter.
3. Use AND / OR in between your Title filters section to control your final result.